# Let $|P(k) -3^k| < 1$ for all $k = 0,\cdots,n$ .Then $P$ has degree at least $n$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $|P(k) -3^k| < 1$ for all $k = 0,\cdots,n$.
My goal is to show that the degree of $P$ is at least $n$.

By induction it suffices to show that no degree $n-1$ polynomial can satisfy the first $n$ constraints and the last one. But after this I am stuck.

Comment: I got it, you can look at the differences of $3^k\pm 1$

Comment: Is $P(x)$ a polynomial?

Comment: yeah it is a poly

Answer (score 1):

So the values at $k=0,1,\ldots, n$ are $3^k+\delta_k$ with $|\delta_k|<1$.
Let $Q(x)=\frac 12(P(x+1)-P(x))$. Then 
for $\deg Q=\deg P-1$ and for $k=0,1,\ldots, n-1$, we have
$$ Q(k)=\frac12(3^{k+1}-3^k)+\underbrace{\frac12(\delta_{k1+}-\delta_k)}_{=:\delta_k'}=3^k+\delta_k'$$
with $|\delta_k'|<1$. With this insight, you can readily prove the claim by induction.